# Type mismatch в БД

Tags: sql, база-данных, access, vba

Есть БД на SQL и Access 2007. Нужно изменить вид отчетов. Есть строчка:

```
rst.Open "SELECT DISTINCT '' AS №, Сум_тек_контр.fio AS ФИО, Сум_тек_контр.dop AS Допуск, Сум_тек_контр.[№ z], Сум_тек_контр.[Sum-Sum-Итого] AS Набрано, '' AS баллы, '' AS Классич, '' AS ECTS, '' AS Подпись INTO vedom1 FROM Сум_тек_контр WHERE (((Сум_тек_контр.[№ гр])=" & rty & wer & wee & ") AND ((Сум_тек_контр.iddis)=" & pred1 & ") AND ((Сум_тек_контр.[уч год])=" & "'" & st & "'" & ")); ", CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenKeyset
```

Она формирует таблицу для отчета, в таблице нужно убрать графы. После удаления одной из них, а конкретно

> Сум_тек_контр.[Sum-Sum-Итого] AS Набрано,

При выписывании отчета появляется ошибка **Type mismatch**. И отчет не выписывается, но выписывается дубликат после повторного нажатия. Я понимаю, что тут какое-то несоответствие типов, но как понять, где именно, не могу. Вот строка для формирование таблицы в дубликате:

```
rst.Open "SELECT DISTINCT '' AS №, Сум_тек_контр.fio AS ФИО, Сум_тек_контр.dop AS Допуск, Сум_тек_контр.[№ z], Сум_тек_контр.[Sum-Sum-Итого] AS Набрано, '' AS баллы, '' AS классическая, '' AS ECTS, '' AS Подпись, Сум_тек_контр.iddis AS ID_Dis_check INTO vedom1 FROM Сум_тек_контр WHERE (((Сум_тек_контр.[№ гр])=" & rty & wer & wee & ") AND ((Сум_тек_контр.[уч год])=" & "'" & st & "'" & ") AND ((Сум_тек_контр.iddis)=" & pred1 & ")); ", CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenDynamic
```

При этом если убрать эту графу в этой строке, то все работает нормально и иногда в некоторых оригиналах ведомостей формируется таблица без ошибок и без графы,а в некоторых с графой.

Я очень надеюсь, что объяснил понятно. Базу делали несколько лет назад, пытаюсь разобраться.

P.S. Если можно сделать так, чтобы столбец просто удалялся из таблицы перед передачей её в Word, то подскажите пожалуйста. Вот код:

```
glav:
Set rst1 = New ADODB.Recordset

rst1.Open "SELECT Nom_ved1.idved, Nom_ved1.date_vid, Nom_ved1.idych, Nom_ved1.ngroup, Nom_ved1.ychgod FROM Nom_ved1 WHERE ((Nom_ved1.idych)=" & pred & ") AND ((Nom_ved1.ngroup)=" & rty & wer & wee & "); ", CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenKeyset
If rst1.RecordCount > 0 Then GoTo Perehod
Set rstProv = New ADODB.Recordset

Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset

'FAIL?!
rst.Open "SELECT DISTINCT '' AS №, Сум_тек_контр.fio AS ФИО, Сум_тек_контр.dop AS Допуск, Сум_тек_контр.[№ z], Сум_тек_контр.[Sum-Sum-Итого] AS Набрано, '' AS Баллы, '' AS Итого, '' AS Классич, '' AS ECTS, '' AS Подпись INTO vedom1 FROM Сум_тек_контр WHERE (((Сум_тек_контр.[№ гр])=" & rty & wer & wee & ") AND ((Сум_тек_контр.iddis)=" & pred1 & ") AND ((Сум_тек_контр.[уч год])=" & "'" & st & "'" & ")); ", CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenKeyset
'Задает вспомогательную таблицу vedom1
Columns(Сум_тек_контр.[Sum-Sum-Итого]).Delete
Set rstNv = New ADODB.Recordset
rstNv.Open "INSERT INTO nom_ved1 ( date_vid, idych, ngroup, ychgod ) VALUES( " & datProv1 & " , " & pred & ", " & rty & wer & wee & ", " & st & "); ", CurrentProject.Connection
'Помещает номер ведомости, дату и уч. год
Set rstNved = New ADODB.Recordset
rstNved.Open "SELECT Nom_ved1.date_vid, Nom_ved1.idved FROM Nom_ved1 WHERE (((Nom_ved1.idych)=" & pred & ") AND ((Nom_ved1.ngroup)=" & rty & wer & wee & ")); ", CurrentProject.Connection
nved = rstNved.Fields(1)
'Определяем номер
Set rst2 = New ADODB.Recordset
rst2.Open "vedom1", CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenKeyset
pred2 = rst2.Fields(4)
dat_dub = datProv
Set rstNk = New ADODB.Recordset
rstNk.Open "SELECT DISTINCT " & nved & " AS idved, " & pred & " AS idych, " & datProv1 & " AS d1, Сум_тек_контр.ins, Сум_тек_контр.[Sum-Sum-Итого] AS f1 INTO vedom22 FROM Сум_тек_контр WHERE (((Сум_тек_контр.[№ гр])=" & rty & wer & wee & ") AND ((Сум_тек_контр.iddis)=" & pred1 & ")); ", CurrentProject.Connection
''''SELECT DISTINCT " & nved & " AS idved, " & pred & " AS idych, " & datProv1 & " AS d1, exp2.ins INTO vedom22 FROM exp2 WHERE (((exp2.[№ гр])=" & rty & wer & wee & "));
Set rstNZ = New ADODB.Recordset
rstNZ.Open "INSERT INTO k_stud1 ( idved, idych, d1, ins, f1 ) SELECT idved, idych, d1, ins, f1 FROM vedom22; ", CurrentProject.Connection
```

Comment: Мне кажется странным, что вы открываете курсор для запроса, который создает таблицу vedom1. Я бы выполнил этот запрос через DOCMD.RUNSQL, а потом открывал курсор уже для vedom1 (если этот курсор вообще нужен).

Comment: если бы я понимал

Comment: Давайте поставим задачу по-другому. Можно ли удалить этот столбец после формировании таблицы и как это сделать? Чтобы в word передалась таблица уже без него. @msi

Comment: Можно просто не добавлять этот столбец в таблицу изначально.
Чтобы удалить столбец из таблицы, в SQL используется такой оператор:
Alter table vedom1 drop column Набрано;

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но я не совсем понимаю. Там ведь в данный момент нет такой таблицы, она создается временно кажется. @msi

Comment: Таблица постоянная. Она в аксессе пересоздается оператором SELECT... INTO. Естественно, сначала её нужно создать, а потом удалить столбец. Но я бы сразу создал таблицу без столбца, который вам не нужен.

Comment: Извините за мою глупость, но в БД SQL, я этой таблицы не нашел, по крайней мере с этим именем. Можете явно указать, что мне сделать? Просто не совсем четко понимаю смысл кода. Только в общих чертах. Есть предположение, что формирование это столбца происходит в части после создания Set rst2 = New ADODB.Recordset @msi

Comment: Запрос SELECT...INTO <имя> создает таблицу с именем "имя" и столбцами, перечисленными после SELECT.

Comment: Мне кажется, что вы не совсем понимаете, в чем дело. Или может я совсем ничего не понимаю. Ошибка эта возникает именно после того, как я убираю этот столбец в запросе **rst.open "SELECT DISTINCT" <имена столбцов> INTO <имя таблицы>** @msi

Comment: CurrentProject.Connection.Execute "alter table vedom1 drop column Набрано"
Пишет, что "Таблица 'vedom1' не может быть заблокирована ядром базы данных. Она уже используется другим пользователем или процессом

Comment: Тогда предварительно нужно закрыть таблицу, если она открыта, или закрыть курсор для этой таблицы.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. @msi

Comment: Не за что. + еще 5 символов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
rst2.Close
CurrentProject.Connection.Execute "ALTER TABLE vedom1 DROP column Набрано"
```